# for 'FyTek.PDFMeld' - Deployment issue in Windows 2008 R2

Tags: .net

I am using PDF Meld to combine one or more PDF files on the fly. The PDF Meld Version (pdfmelddn, cb00bd39a11e4ad8, 8.1.0.0 and PerlRT60, 6.0.1.7918, cea8284aa6739163). The issue happens when I deploy the code to the server Windows Server 2008 R2 (32 Bit) with IIS7. The same code works perfectly in the developer machine Win7. The only difference that I see is I have mapped my website physical path as a network share (//Servername/WebsitePathname). Can you please let me know if there is a known issue with PDF Meld in saving the temporary file in the network share?

The exception is The type initializer for 'FyTek.PDFMeld' threw an exception.

Regards
Anil.S

Comment: I just found its not a problem with the network path or permission. From the dev machine it can save it to the network path.

Comment: There is a newer version of PDF Meld (pdfmelddn, 10.4.0.12080, 944d9b2b197aeacb and Perl510RT901, 9.0.1.31238, cea8284aa6739163) for 32 bit machines. I have upgraded the binaries to this version but the result and exception message are the same.